# How can I use the bump node and wave texture node to create ridged spirals around a vase?

Tags: modeling, node-editor, procedural, texture-coordinates

[image]

I'm trying to replicate the ridged spirals around this vase model that I saw.

[image]

I can't seem to get the spiraled ridges to appear though. I'm using the wave texture node and bump node with texture coordinates and mapping to get the effect that I'm after, but the bump node doesn't seem to be doing anything (the ridges are flat). I tried adding a color ramp node between the texture node and bump node, but it didn't seem to change anything. Is there something that I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like the big thing is that the strength of the bump map is too high; with Strength set to 1, it's trying to treat the bumps as having a maximum height of 1, which is very large compared to the size of your base. Try greatly reducing the bump map's Strength; maybe 0.1 or 0.05.

Also, note that a bump map will always produce "flat" ridges - bump maps use normal-vector trickery to produce the illusion of geometry, but when viewed from this close you'll always be able to see that the bumps aren't real. It may be better to use the "Displacement" option on that far-right node (attach a "Vector Displacement" node, and put your height map into that) combined with the "Displacement and Bump" or "Displacement Only" option in the material, with a subsurf modifier to supply some extra geometry. Displacement will actually move vertices, so it'll make ridges that actually look real.

Comment: Ahhh, I feel a bit silly now. You are totally right. I had tried lowering the strength previously, but the viewport was so close to the object I couldn't tell the difference. I tried viewing it from the camera I had placed (a bit farther away), and it looked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

So there are several problems and it looks like you can fix them this way:

- Decrease the *Distance* value of the *Bump*, try 0.1 for example.
- Increase the object size, it seems to work better.
- Change or add a light source, for example a sun.
- Maybe put a *ColorRamp* between the *Wave* and the *Bump* in order to play with the grooves intensity (there are not a lot of settings in the *Wave Texture*).

[image]