# Wave Texture: How to Take Out Color

Tags: node-editor

I'm giving my selected mesh some distortion and a ruffled look by using the Wave Texture with the Bump vector. It worked, but now my mesh is two different colors, which is not what I wanted. I need it to be one solid color (pink) while keeping the mesh ruffled. I am new to Blender 3.0.0. How should I do this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use the bump node and wave texture node to create ridged spirals around a vase?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185246/how-can-i-use-the-bump-node-and-wave-texture-node-to-create-ridged-spirals-aroun)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is not bicolor. It is the bumping that creates the bands through reflection of light.

But in order to achieve the look I assume you're looking for, it is best to subdivide the mesh and use a Displacement node. Therefore you'll get a proper wavy look.

[image: wavy cube]